# 500 Internal Server error Ms dynamics CRM using adal java

Tags: java, azure, dynamics-crm, adal

I am trying to load accounts from ms dynamics crm using java below is my code.
I got the accesstoken by using the code

```
private static AuthenticationResult getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials() throws Exception {
    AuthenticationContext context = null;
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    ExecutorService service = null;
    try {
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
        /*
         * Replace {client_id} with ApplicationID and {password} with
         * password that were used to create Service Principal above.
         */
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=");
        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken("https://xxxxxxxxxx.api.crm8.dynamics.com",
                credential, null);
        result = future.get();
    } finally {
        service.shutdown();
    }
    if (result == null) {
        throw new ServiceUnavailableException("authentication result was null");
    }
    return result;
}
```

code I am using to load account from dynamics CRM

```
private static String loadAccounts(String token, String userId) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    URL url = new URL(RESOURCE + "/api/data/v8.0/accounts?$select=name&$top=1");
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    connection.addRequestProperty("OData-Version", "4.0");


    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("res code : "+ responseCode);


    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
```

but I am getting the following exception..

```
Access Token - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
UserId - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
res code : 500
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP   
response code: 500 for URL: https://paperflite1.api.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/accounts?$select=name&$top=1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at PublicClient.loadAccounts(PublicClient.java:104)
at PublicClient.main(PublicClient.java:53)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://paperflite1.api.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/accounts?$select=name&$top=1
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at PublicClient.loadAccounts(PublicClient.java:99)
... 1 more
```

Can any one please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the wrong URL for your Web API calls. It should be 
`https://paperflite1.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/accounts?$select=name&$top=1` instead assuming that is your CRM organization URL.